# ¿Por que me muestra el error 'NoReserveMatch' en el metodo reverse pasandole por parametros el nombre de una url que supuestamente esta correcto?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Anteriormente me encontraba trabajando en Django en su version 1.11 y pase a la version 2.0

Esto trajo consigo de que algunas pruebas que tenia definida no me funcionan.

A continuacion les pongo el codigo de una:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from django.urls import reverse

class PingApiTestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.access_token = self.create_access_token() # metodo que me crea un token para el test

    def test_increase_token_time(self):

        url = reverse('ping')
        data = { 'token': self.access_token.token }
        response = self.client.patch(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Esta es la definicion de la url correspondiente al name 'ping' :

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^ping/$', 
    ping_view.PingView.as_view(), 
    name='ping')

]
```

En el test, cuando llega a la linea de invocar el reverse lanza el sigiente error:

> {NoReverseMatch}Reverse for 'ping' not found. 'ping' is not a valid
>   view function or pattern name.

Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, si migraste a 2.0 me parece que tienes que cambiar `url()` por `path()` en la definición de tus URLs.

Comment: ¿Será porque la url requiere una barra al final, es decir `ping/`?

Comment: @abulafia eso no tiene absolutamente nada que ver, la función `reverse()` se usa con el nombre asignado a la URL que en este caso se ha definido como `name='ping'`.

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es:

1. En el fichero urls.py hay que hacer una pequeña refactorizacion debido a la migracion de Django hacia su version 2.0, o sea:

   ```
   from django.urls import path

   urlpatterns = [

   path(r'^ping/$', 
       ping_view.PingView.as_view(), 
       name='ping')
   ]
   ```
2. Debido a que en mi proyecto poseo mas de una aplicacion, en la linea que invoco el metodo `reverse`, en el parametro debo definir tambien la aplicacion de donde proviene la ruta, o sea:

   ```
   def test_increase_token_time(self):
       url = reverse('adminapp:ping')
       data = { 'token': self.access_token.token }
       response = self.client.patch(url, data, format='json')
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
   ```

Comment: Que bueno que lo hayas solucionado. Es cierto, si defines un `namespace` no debes olvidar usarlo en las llamadas a `reverse()`.